# Is there a better way of filling a generic List from a SQL DataAdapter?

Tags: vb.net, generics, data-binding, activerecord

I have an existing application that uses Active Record for its data retrieval. It's in VB.NET (first time I'm doing VB.NET; I usually work in C#). And I'm building a method to return a `List(Of T)` of an object.

The current pattern uses a `SQLDataAdapter` to populate a datatable. I COULD add the record to the `List(Of T)` as I fill the datatable, but there HAS to be a better way to do this.

Any ideas? I'm not married to using `SQLDataAdapter`, if there's a better way that avoids it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've still not had any responses...

I haven't used Active Record myself, so I don't know at what point that makes any kind of difference but it strikes me that reading into a `DataTable` *and* a `List<T>` is duplicating things somewhat.

How about populating the `List<T>` from a `SqlDataReader` instead? As you move through the results using `Read()`, create a new object from the current row and add it to the list. If you need to do it for various different types, I'd write a generic method to do it, along the lines of:

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this SqlDataReader reader,
    Func<SqlDataReader, T> rowConverter)
{
    List<T> ret = new List<T>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ret.Add(rowConverter(reader));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Then you can implement the converter with a lambda expression or anonymous method.

Alternatively you could make the extension method target the command instead of the `SqlDataReader` - it could deal with calling `ExecuteReader`, converting every row and then disposing of the reader afterwards.

(It's a slightly odd signature because `SqlDataReader` represents both the iterator *and* the current row; just a quirk of the API.)

I'm probably missing something deeper though - if this doesn't help, could you explain why, perhaps as a question edit?

Comment: nope, that's all I wanted... a way to get around the redundant data objects. Thanks!

Comment: I think you're missing a ToList<T>

Comment: This won't compile. I changed this to public static List<T> ToList<T>

Comment: @ScottE: Right, yes, it should be generic - that wasn't clear from your previous comment. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! Likely you wrote that without an IDE straight from your brain, which is pretty badass.